# integral problem $\int \frac{2 \lambda a}{\mathbf{ (e^{at}-1)\lambda \sigma^2+2ae^{-at}}}dt $

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

Does anybody know how to tackle the below integral? I am analyzing a formula derivation where this appears as the final calculation, but I don't know how to get it solved

$$\int \frac{2 \lambda a}{\mathbf{ (e^{at}-1)\lambda \sigma^2+2ae^{-at}}}dt $$

this should result in
$$\frac{2ab \ \big{[} \ at+log(2a)+log \big{(} \mathbf{(e^{at}-1)\lambda \sigma^2 +2ae^{-at}}\big{)} \ \big{]}}{\sigma^2}$$

Comment: I would start with the [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) on $\displaystyle \frac{1}{z+\alpha+\beta /z} = \frac{z}{z^2+\alpha z+\beta} = z\frac{1}{(z-\rho_1)(z-\rho_2)} = z(\frac{A}{z-\rho_1}+ \frac{B}{z-\rho_2})$ (when $\rho_1 \ne \rho_2$)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Note that the integral can be written

$$\int \frac{2 \lambda a}{ (e^{at}-1)\lambda \sigma^2+2ae^{-at}}\,dt=\int \frac{2 \lambda a e^{at}}{e^{at} (e^{at}-1)\lambda \sigma^2+2a}\,dt$$

Now, enforce the substitution $x=e^{at}$ with $dx=ae^{at}\,dt$ and evaluate the integral

$$\int \frac{2\lambda}{\lambda \sigma^2x(x-1)+2a}\,dx$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark